# WPF RichTextBox every new characted on new line

Tags: c#, wpf, richtextbox

By unknown reson, my RichTextBox prints every new character on next line, and I have no ideas why can it be so. I am not an expert, but I am sure what it don't have to work this way.

Here is how it looks like:
[Always on new line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZPxqn.png)

Here is part of code what is responsible for this RichTextBox:
[Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uhi3X.png)

local:RichTextBoxHelper.DocumentXaml binding doesn't matter, I added it already after saw this problem, so problem is not caused by it.

Could someone tell me please, what could be source of problem?

Answer (score 0):

The `RichTextBox` lay out the content (`RichTextBox.FlowDocument`) dynamically based on the size of the view window.

In your case seems like the `FlowDocument` page width doesn’t set correctly. More likely the `PageWidth` or `MaxPageWidth` property set to `0`.

You is necessary to analyze these properties and set the values correctly.

*NOTE: Look at the `FlowDocument.PageWidth` comments:*

```cs
//     Gets or sets the preferred width for pages in a System.Windows.Documents.FlowDocument.
//
// Returns:
//     The preferred width, in device independent pixels, for pages in the System.Windows.Documents.FlowDocument.
//     A value of System.Double.NaN (equivalent to an attribute value of "Auto") causes
//     the page width to be determined automatically. The default is System.Double.NaN.
public double PageWidth { get; set; }
```

*And additional description you can find here: https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationFramework/src/Framework/System/Windows/Documents/FlowDocument.cs*